# Do you need a Custom Adapter to add different view children to a ListView

Tags: java, android, xml, listview, adapter

I want to create a ListView with alternating row layouts.

```
Row 1 - Layout A
Row 2 - Layout B
Row 3 - Layout A etc.
```

Is it necessary to create a Custom Adapter for that or is it by default possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No you can't do this without Adapter, but look at `getViewTypeCount()` and `getItemViewType(postion)` of the [BaseAdapter](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/BaseAdapter.html) class, as they will support you.

First let your Adapter know how much different types your rows have; in your case they are 2 (Layout A, and Layout B).

The second method returns the type for the given position. In your case it could be something easy like the following code.

```
@Override
public int getItemViewType(int postion){
    return (postion % 2);
```

See: http://android.amberfog.com/?p=296 for more information.

Answer (score 1):

If you don't have that many items in your list, you don't necessarily need to use a `ListView` or adapter at all.

For a similar result, you can use a `LinearLayout` within a `ScrollView`.

This way, you can add the items to your `LinearLayout` on creation of your activity with the relevant style based on the position within the list.

Saying that, if your list will have lots (very vague I know) of items, then it's much more memory efficient to use a `ListView`

I'd personally use this method if a) there aren't that many items and b) you're not inserting/removing items from the list at run time (apart from the initial build), otherwise you'll have to go through each item adjusting its style.

Comment: Thanks for the input, I had a little look at that and I am more interested in the ListView's caching of views as the end goal would be to have a large amount of items to scroll through.

Answer (score 0):

You have to develop your own layouts and adapter, using default adapter, you can't choose the layout you want to put.